# Использовать чужие картинки из интернета в приложении android?

Tags: android, google-play, авторские-права

Много где пишут, что так нельзя. Но ведь не всегда. Можно, например, брать картинки со стоков или любые картинки со свободной лицензией. И тут вроде всё понятно, если ты крадёшь картинку, то можешь рассчитывать только на то, что тебе повезёт и автор на тебя не пожалуется, но. меня привлекла возможность `embed'ить` картинки, хотя я так и не понял, как конкретно это делать. Просто написать код с интернет-ссылками, по которым программа будет загружать картинки? Для каких картинок этот метод прокатит?
Также другой вопрос: если отфотошопить картинку до неузнаваемости, совмещая её с другими, так что все картинки потеряют своё изначальное значение, будет ли это считаться моим творчеством?

Comment: Это юридический вопрос, он не имеет отношения непосредственно к программированию.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это необходимо знать при работе с любым материалом, и графическим в том числе. Я постараюсь кратко описать суть.

Если вы используйте чьи-то работы, вам необходимо учитывать ресурс, с которого вы берете информацию, — у данного ресурса должна быть лицензия по распространению и использованию (чаще мы привыкли видеть способы: платный/бесплатный). Если таковой не наблюдается, при использовании данного материала правообладатель (проще, автор) имеет полное право предъявить свои требования по использованию данного материала. Это значит, что вы незаконно используете его работы.

Второй момент: очень аккуратно (никогда) не используйте фотографии людей, если они не имеют авторского подтверждения, — такие дела быстро заканчиваются не в вашу пользу, и их сейчас много. Причём если автор жалуется на приложение с таким материалом, будьте уверены, что ваше приложение и ваш аккаунт будут заблокированы в ближайшее время.

Третий момент — отредактированное фото. Здесь тонкая нить, но да — это работает. Если вы не просто изменили цвет, а действительно обработали текстуры и наложили кучу эффектов, автору сложно (невозможно) будет доказать, что это его работа.